# Why is my programme showing Segmentation Fault on Ubuntu but working fine on Geeks IDE?

Tags: c, operating-system, ubuntu-16.04, scheduling

Experts, this is the program I made for First Come First Serve Scheduling in C language. 

For the inputs like - 
4
0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4

and inputs like - 
5
0 1 2 3 4
4 3 1 2 5

My program is giving Segmentation fault (Core dumped) when I tried running it on my Ubuntu but it worked fine on GeeksForGeeks IDE.

And for the inputs like -
6
4 3 2 1 2 3
4 3 2 3 4 5

My program is working fine on my Ubuntu as well as on GeeksForGeeks IDE.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    int n,i;
    printf("\nEnter the number of jobs:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int at[n],bt[n],at_copy[n];
    printf("\nEnter the arrival time:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&at[i]);
        at_copy[i]=at[i];   
    }    
    printf("\nEnter the burst time:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&bt[i]);
    int priority[n],min=at_copy[0],k,j;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        min=at_copy[0];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(at_copy[i]<min){
                min=at_copy[i];
                k=i;
            }
        }
        at_copy[k]=999;
        priority[j]=k;
    }
    int ct[n],wt[n],tat[n],t=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(at[i]<t)
            k=0;
        else
            k=at[i];
        t+=bt[i]+k;
        ct[i]=t;
        tat[i]=ct[i]-at[i];
        wt[i]=tat[i]-bt[i];
    }
    printf("\nProcess\tAT\tBT\tCT\tTAT\tWT\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       printf("P%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",i+1,at[i],bt[i],ct[i],tat[i],wt[i]);
    }
}
```

In the output, I am expecting a table like structure displaying the arrival time, burst time, completion time, burst time, turnaround time and waiting time of all the processes.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: 1. (i+1), 2. (at[i]), 3. (bt[i]),4. (ct[i]), 5. (tat[i]) and 6. (wt[i])  

It's easy to lose track, but it appears there's 6 parameters

Comment: @Daniel Indeed. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, it is better to use : int main(void)

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
int priority[n],min=at_copy[0],k,j;
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    min=at_copy[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(at_copy[i]<min){
            min=at_copy[i];
            k=i;
        }
    }
    at_copy[k]=999;
    ...
```

Imagine what happens, when `at_copy[0]` is the minimal value. Then, the condition `atcopy[i]<min` is never true and k remains uninitialized resulting in an out-of-bounds access here:

```
    at_copy[k]=999;
```

You have to initialize k with `0`, since you assume in the first iteration, that `at_copy[0]` is the minimum.

```
int priority[n],min=at_copy[0],k=0,j;
```

With Geeks-IDE, you might have been "lucky" and k had the value 0 without being initialized.

Comment: Hello Ctx! Thanks a lot for replying. It worked! I'm so grateful to you!